# How do I format a corrupted, write locked SD card?

Tags: formatting, sd-card

A while back a power outage corrupted the SD card I was using on my RaspberryPi that was running raspiOS. I switched out the SD card and carried on.

I recently attempted to reformat that corrupted SD card but I cant get it out of a read only state. My main computer uses windows so all of my attempts of unlocking the SD card were in Windows10.

Ive tried….

- Using macrium reflect, the card doesn’t show up since its not formatted in windows
- Using diskpart in cmd
- Changing the write protect key in regedit

Is there a way to salvage the SD card? Theres nothing important on it, im just trying to get some more use out of it.

Comment: I trust you have already switched the hardware write protection toggle to off-position? https://www.diskpart.com/screenshot/en/others/others/move-lock-switch-to-remove-write-protection.png

Comment: You can download the contents for a replacement SD Card from the raspberry Pi website. Just replace the card

Comment: Here is the link for downloads:  http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads

Comment: Bin it. There probably isn't much more you can do.